# Remove children element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list children element about >50 value:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="children"></div>
   <div class="children"></div>
   ...
   <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to remove children eq from 1 to 30. Can you help me anyway to solve this problem quickly?
Thank you very much.

Comment: @Barmar I want to remove 30 value or more. Are you have anyway help speed fast? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. The question says you want to remove the first 30 children. What do you mean by 30 or more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with jQuery's [**`:lt()`**](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector:

> Select all elements at an ***index*** less than ***index*** within the matched set.

```
$('.parent > .children:lt(30)').remove(); //Remove the first 30
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('.parent > .children:lt(2)').remove(); // Remove the first 2
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="children">1</div>
   <div class="children">2</div>

   <div class="children">3</div>
</div>
```